# Send XML over request and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, api, request

I'm trying to send XML data to an API but I don't get any response but  `<html></html>`
.The question is if I'm doing something wrong or the target server...

Can I send the XML as a string in using request ? 
like:

```
var xml = '' +
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
  '<Request version="1.0">' +
  '<Header>'+
  '<Security sender="'+ 123456 +'" />' +
  '</Header>' +
  ' <Transaction mode="LIVE">' +
  '     <User login="'+ login +'" pwd="'+ pwd +'"/>' +
  ' </Transaction>' +
  '</Request> '

// request type 1  
    request.post({
      headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'charset' : 'UTF-8'},
      url:     'https://test.url.io',
      body:    xml
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if (error) { return console.log(err); }
      console.log(body);
    });
```

Same `<html></html>` result when I use XMLHttpRequest

```
// request type 2
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://test.url.io",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('charset', 'UTF-8');
xmlhttp.send(escape(xml));
```

Here the API description:

**Request Encoding**
For all requests the request header must contain the Content-Type / charset parameter with the
charset encoding set to “UTF-8”. The actual content type may differ; the decisive information is the charset 
Platform Documentation – XML Integrator 7
value.

Accordingly, all request data must be encoded using the UTF-8 character set.
For XML data, please use the following Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Examples:
Integration via PHP/cURL: http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
 ));

// attach parameter
curl_exec($ch);
```

Integration via Java:

```
 UrlRequest req = new UrlRequest(UrlRequest.POST, CORE_URL );
    // attach parameter to request
    req.addHeaderParam("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    req.send();
```

Comment: You've set your content type wrong. Should be `application/xml`.

Comment: in the api -description it says "For XML data, please use the following Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: then that server is doing something very, very odd. Can you post a link (or better yet inline a quote) from those docs?

Comment: Seems weird to use that content type for XML.... Are you positive they want xml?

Comment: yes...they want it as xml...

Comment: @Samy that's got to be a mistake. And a double mistake for giving you an empty `html` tag instead of an error page (with appropriate HTTP code). Change it to `application/xml;charset=UTF-8;` like I said and see what happens.